# disable button in gridview

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview

I have a Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvtransaction" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="60%" OnRowDataBound="gvtransaction_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Consumer">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblfirstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Amount") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcurrencyID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcurrencyname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateCreated">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbldatecreated" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateCreated") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnClick="btnApprove_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClick="btnReject_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

here is the code for the onclick = "btnApprove_click():

```
 GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;

    string id = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblid")).Text;
    Response.Write(row.RowIndex);
    string ApprovedStatus = "Approved";

    Button btnApprove = (Button)sender;
    btnApprove.Enabled = false;

    string status = ClassBiller.ConsumerAcceptedStatus(int.Parse(id), ApprovedStatus, DateTime.Now);
    ViewPendingConsumer(); //rebind gridview para magEffect yun update
```

my concern is, how can i disable the buttons inside my gridview when i clicked either the Approve Button or the Reject Button.

sample scenario:
when I click Approve, the buttons should be disabled so that the it will prevent the user to click the button again..

I have read some articles which suggests the use of gridview's onrowdatabound..But i am confuse on how to do it...

I tried using

```
row.Enabled = false;
```

still doesnt work...

help please..
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `rowdatabound` event of `Grid View`, Firstly Find the control by using `FindControl` method like

```
protected void gvtransaction_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        // For `Approve` button
        Button btnapprove = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnApprove"); // give property id of button form template field
        btnapprove.Enabled = true; //true means enable else you may set false to disable button 

        // For `Reject` button
        // Same condition but in `FindControl` method use `btnReject` id.
        }
    }
```

That's for `Approve` button For `Reject` button you may use same logic.

[Link For Help](http://forums.asp.net/t/1876325.aspx/1)

Hope it clear and works for you.

Comment: is Button btnApprove = (Button)e.Row.FindCotrol("btnApprove"); the same with GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow; ?

Comment: when i added codes, i get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. and its pointing at btnapprove.Enabled = true;

Comment: i forget to add an important line of that event, now i added plz check and try once.

Comment: when i am debugging it, on pageload it fires the onrowdatabound method..then it goes to the gridview codes..then, when i click the button, it doesn't go throught the if statement..

Comment: `RowDataBound` Occurs when a data row is bound to data in a GridView control.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31296/discussion-between-aianlee-and-rahul)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the button inside its click event. But when your gridview databinds again, the button will be enabled back..

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnApprove = (Button)sender;
    btnApprove.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do, where Cells[5] is the cell where you have your Button, had the same problem and it worked for me.

protected void gvtransaction_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

       e.Row.Cells[5].Enabled = false;
    }

}
```